# How do I promisify node-adodb?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to promisify `node-adodb` using [bluebirdjs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html).

I've tried this:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import ADODB from 'node-adodb'

const db = ADODB.open(`...`)
const dbQuery = db.query(`...`)
const dbQueryOn = Promise.promisify(dbQuery.on, { context: dbQuery })

dbQueryOn('done').then(data => {
  console.log('data =', data)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('err =', err)
})
```

The data is returned, but it comes via the `.catch()` not the `.then()` method.

How do I get `node-adodb` working with promises..?

Comment: Sounds like they have their callback parameters in reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `node-adodb`, but from its documentation it seems it uses a non-conventional way of returning errors and results (using event-like emitters).

Bluebird's `promisify` requires the regular Node.js callback convention (first argument represents errors, second argument represents the "result" value), so you can't use it in this situation.

But you can wrap it yourself:

```
const db = ADODB.open(`...`);

const runQuery = query => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(query)
      .on('done', resolve)
      .on('fail', reject);
  });
}

// Usage:
runQuery(`...`).then(data => {
  console.log('data =', data)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('err =', err)
})
```